# Rust serde How deserialize xml "weird" lists?

Tags: xml, rust, serde

Im trying to deserialize  this style of xml list that are not technically a list but behaves like one:

```xml
<list>
    <id-00001>
        <name type="string">Pedro</name>
        <age type="number">37</age>
    </id-00001>
    <id-00002>
        <name type="string">Alex</name>
        <age type="number">30</age>
    </id-00002>
<list>
```

The number of items on the "list" is variable and will only increment the number(x) on the `id-0000x`.

The issue is that i cant think how to map this to a Rust struct using serde.

Im trying to do something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename = "list")]
struct List {
    people: Vec<Person>
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8
}
```

but I don't know how to deal with the `id-0000x` tags.

Edit:
this are the dependencies that im using:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.117", features = ["derive"] }
serde-xml-rs = "0.4.0"
```

Thanks for the help in advance.
Regards

Comment: What you need is a parser, not `serde`.

Comment: Why do `age` tags end in `prof`?

Comment: could you please point me to an example of a parser solving a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Tomas Hurst suggestion if solve the issues using something like this:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer}; // 1.0.94
use serde_xml_rs;
use std::collections::HashMap;

const XML: &str = r#"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root version="1">
    <list>
        <id-00001>
            <name type="string">Pedro</name>
            <age type="number">37</age>
        </id-00001>
        <id-00002>
            <name type="string">Alex</name>
            <age type="number">30</age>
        </id-00002>
    </list>
</root>
"#;

#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize)]
struct List {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_list")]
    list: Vec<Person>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
}

fn deserialize_list<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<Vec<Person>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let people_raw: HashMap<String, Person> = Deserialize::deserialize(d)?;
    let people: Vec<Person> = people_raw.values().map(|person| person.clone()).collect();
    Ok(people)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let data: List = serde_xml_rs::from_str(XML)?;
    println!("{:?}", data);
    Ok(())
}
```

output:

```sh
List { list: [Person { name: "Pedro", age: 37 }, Person { name: "Alex", age: 30 }] }
```

Comment: Instead of the .map(...), you can use .cloned(), though best might be an .into_iter() to grab the owned values directly.  Also note by using a HashMap you're losing ordering, hence my use of a BTreeMap to order by keys.

Comment: In the end i dont care about the ordering, I just want the array, i will take a look to the into_iter to avoid the copy. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest just to deserialize the tags:

```
struct List(BTreeMap<String, Person>);
```

This will get you an ordered collection of "id-bla" => Person pairs.